# DropDownList content appearing in engine search results

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, seo

I am managing an online store where customers can select their country from a `DropDownList` to calculate the shipping costs of their orders, but I've found that the results of search engines are showing the list of countries in this control.

Anyone knows any accepted SEO practice to avoid this from happening?

**CODE ADDED**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CbCountry" DataTextField="Country" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="IdCountry" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The `DropDownList` is filled from database with this function:

```
CbCountry.Items.Clear()
CbCountry.DataSource = (New CountryManager).GetCountries(lang)
CbCountry.DataBind()

If CInt(0 & Country) > 0 Then
    CbCountry.SelectedValue = Country
End If
```

Comment: I say to let it as it is and is not your job for what the search engines show and work. If you won to not show it to SS, you can chose to not populate it when the request coming from SS, or you can make it dynamically using an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple check using the `Request.Browser.Crawler` like

```
IF Request.Browser.Crawler Then
  CbCountry.Visible = false
Else
  CbCountry.Items.Clear()
  CbCountry.DataSource = (New CountryManager).GetCountries(lang)
  CbCountry.DataBind()

  If CInt(0 & Country) > 0 Then
      CbCountry.SelectedValue = Country
  End If
End if
```

is very simple, but I can not see the reason for do that.

Comment: It's not my decision: the shop owner wants it this way... and thanks for your answer!